# Where can one find the original bengali book of Bhaktivinoda Thakura's Jaiva Dharma?

Tags: scripture, vaishnavism, bhakti, gaudiya-vaishnavism

I am look for the book Jaiva Dharma by Srila Bhaktivinoda Thakura, an important Gaudiya Vaishnava Acharya. Any idea where i can find it?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some links where it is available:

1. https://archive.org/details/1_20191030_20191030_1133/mode/2up
2. http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/932?mode=full
3. https://archive.org/details/SriJaivaDharma
4. https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.456789/mode/2up
5. https://bn.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A6%AA%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A4%E0%A6%BE:%E0%A6%B6%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%B0%E0%A7%80%E0%A6%9C%E0%A7%88%E0%A6%AC%E0%A6%A7%E0%A6%B0%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%AE%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%AE.djvu/%E0%A7%A7